# Using HTML string in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How would I modify the following to accept an HTML string rather than load a file? I need to create HTML on the fly and pass it to the UIWebView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"emergency" ofType:@"html"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

That is a method on UIWebView. See the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I come from the PHP world and I'm patiently waiting for the moment when Objective-C snaps and everything makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps you....just paste in button action

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 320, 460)];
[wv loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><a href='http://iosstoryboard.blogspot.in'>Click Me</a></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:wv];//wait for some seconds to load.
```